# Memory in cache in C

Tags: c, caching

Is there some way to find out if memory I have requested is cached or not? And if so, it would be helpful to know in which level of cache is that chunk of memory stored.

I had an idea that adress of pointer might change when its cached but it looks like that doesnt work.

Edit: it is for university project and I have access to multiple machines with different OSs so almost any solution would help.

Comment: This depends heavily on the hardware and software you use. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: First paragraphe: The C standard does not provide such a thing. Maybe the OS may provide such a service. Second paragraph: _I had an idea that adress of pointer might change when its cached but it looks like that doesnt work._: can you elaborate? What does not work?

Comment: What level of caching are you talking about? You won't find any modern CPU that doesn't already cache in hardware and you really shouldn't care. This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What problem are you _actually_ trying to solve: Read this: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: If you want to study cache usage, I can recommend cachegrind (a valgrind subsystem) or "perf", both available on linux

Comment: Well, I doubt it is XY problem because this is literaly what I need to do, access memory and find out if that memory was or was not in a cache. Thats whole point of program I had asigned.
Point is to test memory caching algorithms and create sequence that will result in a cache miss.

Comment: Asking if something is in cache is meaningless because the answer is stale before you can do anything with it. There are things outside of your control  that can change the state of the cache including the code you run to find out if something is in the cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I had an idea that adress of pointer might change when its cached but
>   it looks like that doesnt work.

You probably misunderstand how caching works. Caching is a separate memory, yes, and it has it's own addresses, but when the CPU caches memory lines from RAM, it keeps a record of what RAM-addresses the memory was on, and keeps a map between RAM-address and cache-address. From the point of view of your program, the address is the same. If your program requires an address, and the CPU sees that address in the map (a cache hit, a success), the CPU translates the address on the fly and gets the data from cache instead of from RAM.

> Is there some way to find out if memory I have requested is cached or
>   not?

From a high level language (like C), no there is not. The operating system can theoretically (depending on CPU architecture) find out if addresses are cached, but this is not anything you can rely on with C.

See [Can i check if a chunk of memory (e.g., allocated using malloc) stays in the cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822932/can-i-check-if-a-chunk-of-memory-e-g-allocated-using-malloc-stays-in-the-cac])

Comment: Pointer is vitual adress so I knew that it probably wont change but that was only thing that came to my mind. But thank you for that link, it looks like I will be able to do what I need to do by measuring access time.

Comment: If you question is "how can I", then don't ask "is there a way". There are ways, timing memory accesses and similar. There are however several pitfalls when doing very detailed timings like these.

Comment: It's worth noting that C doesn't provide any **standard** way to do this. However, that's not stopping an OS from having some syscall or something similarly platform-dependent that could give you that data -- maybe even by using embedded assembly. The thing is that there's no platform-independent way to do this; if you want to, you need to figure out if your CPU allows it, and if it does, how that works, then use that information to construct a platform-dependent way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already requested any memory chunk, **for sure** is cached.

When any memory address is requested, a check in first cache level is made, if it fails, then a check in second level and so on.

Once the block where that address belongs to is found, the whole block is placed inside first level of cache, due to [principle of locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference), in order to avoid additional searches for the same block (for instance, if you access the same address or consecutive ones) which is common in almost every program (for loops, indexes, etc)

Comment: This depends on caching policy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies) and optional no-cache pages, etc.

Comment: @dbrank0 Yes, but the replacement policy determines which already cached block will be deleted in order to emplace the new one. Whenever you try to access a memory block, it will be copied to cache memory. If it doesn't, or does selectively, the memory hierarchy won't work as intended

Comment: Yes, I was typing faster than thinking. There is probably no practical caching algorighm that does not read data into cache on read-miss (barring nocache pages).